# how to present a list inside a list in jsf page

Tags: jsf

I am a new user to this group and asking my first question.
Actually i am working on an application in jsf using rich faces, where i need to show a list in data table which again consists of two nested list. I am not able ot provide rowspan for my first column . please suggest.

Regards
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1. Look at `<rich:subTable>`
2. Iterate over your lists inside a
   column using `<ui:repeat>`
   (facelets) or `a4j:repeat`
   (richfaces)